# Unable to mount Parallels Tools to virtual CDROM

Tags: mount, cd-drive, parallels

I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.10 in Parallels Desktop12 on my Mac but I failed to install Parallels Tools. I tried to mount the Tools.iso manually to the virtual CDROM, but it shows:

```
Error mounting /dev/sr0 at /media/haohui/Parallels Tools:Command-line'mount -t "iso9660"-o
```

[image: Screenshot of error message]

I installed the Tools successfully after I first installed Ubuntu, but after I reinstall the system, the error occurs. I'm new in Ubuntu and I want to know what causes this error? And how to solve it?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually mount it: http://kb.parallels.com/en/113394

Comment: I finally find a solution to this problem. 
It's an alternative way to install Parallels Tools on VMs. 
Just log into the VMs and download prl-tools-lin.iso image file from the web. Then install it on VMs' disk instead of mounting it to CDROM.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I had to do to get Parallel Tools installed on Ubuntu 18.04, which should also work for your use case. Inside a terminal window, do the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
cd /media/cdrom
sudo ./install
```

Then reboot the machine and you should be good to go.